# How to retrieve selected value of radio button from fetch array result..?

Tags: php, mysql, radio-button

i want to get value of selected value of radio button in fetched records.. i am not getting radio button value...tell me if it is right or wrong..  in this case it is dynamic.. if it was static there is no problem.. but this is dynamic..how to do that..? or any alternate way.. any help would be appreciable..

```
<?php
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>". "<input type='radio' name= 'Returns' 
value=".$res['T_no'].")>". "</td>";
echo "<td>".$res['T_no']."</td>";
?>

<form action="sample.php" method="POST" class="form-inline">
<input type="submit" value="Get Sch"/>
</form>

sample.php

<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if ($con) {
$db = mysql_select_db('tdb', $con);
} else {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

echo "you have selected :".$_POST['Returns']; // Displaying Selected Value

echo $POST['Returns'];

$selected_val = $_POST['Returns'];  // Storing Selected Value In  Variable
echo "You have selected :" .$selected_val;  // Displaying Selected Value

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t_detail WHERE 
T_No='$selected_val'");

mysql_close($con)
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have used `$_POST['Returns[]']` it should be `$_POST['Returns']`. as this is an array so you can either `implode` it or use `foreach` to get each radio button value

You can do as below:

```
<form action="schedule.php" method="POST" class="form-inline">
<?php
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>". "<input type='radio' name= 'Returns' 
value=".$res['Train_no'].")>". "</td>";
echo "<td>".$res['Train_no']."</td>";
?>
<input type="submit" value="Get Schedule"/>
</form>
```

==============

```
$implode = implode(',',$selected_val);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM train_detail WHERE 
Train_No='".$implode."'");
```

Comment: ...thanks ..i am editing my  $_POST['Returns']..  how to use foreach ....

Comment: it gives ...Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed

Comment: again updated the code , you need to use the form tag first and load your checkbox code inside the form to get the formdata on schedule.php

Comment: ..hey.. i am getting value :) but still shows warning...i am posting my result page image...below code..

Comment: ..Yes it works... i am adding my result image below code.. :)

Comment: hi how to fetch time in HH:MM format only...in mysql fetch array...i don't want to use second to be display...